# python - Using both logging and warnings module throws 'TypeError: expected a character buffer object'

Tags: python, logging, warnings

I'm trying to use both the `logging` and `warnings` modules in a python script. I want to log warnings using `warnings.warn()` but still have them use the formatting I set for my logger.

I'm calling both `logging.captureWarnings(True)` and replacing `warnings.formatwarning()` with my own function. My code looks like this:

```
def _my_format_warning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None):
    logging.warning(message)

# ... rest of code

# setup in main function:
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.WARNING)
logging.captureWarnings(True)
warnings.formatwarning=_my_format_warning
```

Testing the various options:

1. If I don't override `warnings.formatwarning()` with my own function, I get the built-in warning formatting, which contains newlines and fields that I do not want (marked below in **bold**):

   > [2015-01-07 21:40:43,436] WARNING: **robots.py:435: UserWarning:** Robot schematic contains less than 1 laser attachment.
   >   **"laser attachment.".format(self.MIN_RECOMMENDED_LASERS)**
2. If I override `warnings.formatwarning()` but don't call `logging.captureWarnings(True)`, my script crashes on an exception:

   > [2015-01-07 21:40:43,436] WARNING: Robot schematic contains less than 1 laser attachment.
   >   Traceback (most recent call last):
   >   File "robots.py", line 435, in activate()
   >    "laser attachment.".format(self.MIN_RECOMMENDED_LASERS)
   >   File "warnings.py", line 29, in _show_warning
   >    file.write(formatwarning(message, category, filename, lineno, line))
   >   TypeError: expected a character buffer object

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[The specification](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.formatwarning) for `warnings.formatwarning()` says "This [function] returns a string". This means to fully implement the function interface your function must return a string also.

Change your function to return the warning message you want to print as a string. Like this:

```
def _my_format_warning(message, category, filename, lineno, line=None):
    return message
```

You can then both call `logging.captureWarnings(True)` and override `warnings.formatwarning()` with your own function, and warnings will print correctly with the desired format.

The error message `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` is happening because `warnings.showwarning()` is trying to write the value returned by your custom `_my_format_warning()` function to `std.out`, but can't. Since your function doesn't return anything, `None` is returned by default ([see here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#return)). Python can't print any warning messages to `None`, because it is not a character or buffer object.